# How to keep DB table id updated according to a reverse chronological order with latest id 1

Tags: php, mysql

M working on mysql and I have to print the data in the table in reverse chronological order.
Also I want that the name printed on top should have id 1 both on the screen as well as in the db. i.e ech time it gets updated as the number of entries increase.
I have used the following code but it doesnt help:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY date DESC";
$count=1;

while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    $temp = $row['added_name'];
    $query = "UPDATE table SET id = '$count'";
    mysql_query($query,$conn);
    echo "<tr>
            <td>".$row['id']."</td>
            <td>".$row['added_name']."</td>
            <td>".$row['date']."</td>
          </tr>";
    $count++;
}
```

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Comment: What is wrong with the code? What is your expected result?

Comment: You want to re-index the entire database, everytime a row is added to the database. That is slow and eficient. Just use PHP to display numbers the way you want, and keep the database id's the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will tell you how to do this, but I promise you, you really do NOT want to do this. As Husman said, you should just display a 1 but have it link to the real database record id number.

Anyway if you decide to ignore the good advice you would do this:

Before inserting the new record, run the query:

```
UPDATE table SET id = id+1 ORDER BY id DESC
```

then insert your new record with an id of 1

Answer (score 0):

Since you do not clearly state what is happening and what is going wrong, I can only guess. The thing I see is that you are updating the ID's of the database items incorrectly.

Notice:

```
$query = "UPDATE table SET id = '$count'";
```

You are telling the database to update the table and set ALL `id`'s to `$count`. With this, everytime you run this, ALL of the ID's are changed to the same value. You want to add a `where` statement so you're only updating the current item, as such:

```
$query = "UPDATE table SET id = '$count' WHERE added_name = '$temp'";
```

or

```
$query = "UPDATE table SET id = '$count' WHERE date = '{$row['date']}'";
```

I used the variable given in the code. You may use any other value that will be unique to that item or build a larger `where` statement.